# Extract images from HTML file using python standard libraries

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

so I'm trying to write a script that basically parses through an HTML file, finds all the images and saves those images into another folder. How would one accomplish this only using libraries that come with python3 when you install it on your computer? I currently have this script that I would like to incorporate more into.

```
date = datetime.date.today()
backup_path = os.path.join(str(date), language)
if not os.path.exists(backup_path):
    os.makedirs(backup_path)

log = []

endpoint = zendesk + '/api/v2/help_center/en-us/articles.json'
while endpoint:
    response = requests.get(endpoint, auth=credentials)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Failed to retrieve articles with error {}'.format(response.status_code))
    exit()
data = response.json()

for article in data['articles']:
    if article['body'] is None:
        continue
    title = '<h1>' + article['title'] + '</h1>'
    filename = '{id}.html'.format(id=article['id'])
    with open(os.path.join(backup_path, filename), mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(title + '\n' + article['body'])

    print('{id} copied!'.format(id=article['id']))

    log.append((filename, article['title'], article['author_id']))

endpoint = data['next_page']
```

This is a script I found on a zendesk forum that basically backs up our articles on Zendesk.

Comment: Why not use Beautiful Soup?

Comment: it doesn't look like you've shared the full code, but I suppose you'd want to swap out requests with [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using beautiful soup to retrieve all the  nodes and for each node using urllib to get the picture.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#note here using response.text to get raw html
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

#get the src of all images
img_source = [x.src for x in soup.find_all("img")]

#get the images
images = [urllib.urlretrieve(x) for x in img_source]
```

And you probably need to add some error handling and change it a bit to fit your page, but the idea remains the same.

Comment: BeautifulSoup and urllib are shipped with Anaconda Python3 installation.

Comment: Then maybe using re to extract the <img> tags? I'm not familiar with regular expression though, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys! I'll try it out